# Can Confluent's S3 Sink Connector for Kafka Connect write topics to a nested (not a top-level) folder in an S3 bucket using `topics.dir`?

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform, s3-kafka-connector

Can Confluent's S3 Sink Connector for Kafka Connect write topics to a nested (not a top-level) folder in an S3 bucket using `topics.dir`?

For example, if I set `topics.dir` to the value `thisistoplevel/thisisnested`, will the connector work?

The [documentation](https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connect-s3-sink/current/configuration_options.html#storage) for the `topics.dir` configuration property says:

> Top level directory to store the data ingested from Kafka.

But it seems like a strange restriction to make. Perhaps the wording "Top level directory" is meant to mean something more like "the top-most directory under which topics will be written".

Maybe someone else has tested this or uses a nested directory in production?

Answer (score 1):

In S3's context, there is no such thing as "nesting" of folders; S3 does not have "folders". It is rather just a string prefix within a bucket.

Yes, the prefix can be as long as you need it, and then topic names will be appended to that path when written

Comment: Thanks! I was aware of the fact that folders are not a first-class concept in S3 (though I think there's some handling of prefix delimiter characters the details of which are a bit beyond me), but I forgot to consider that here with respect to this question. Makes sense!